# Is it possible to change the units from px to em in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've been doing all `em` based coding, so when I inspect my element and get a width in `px`, it's just an extra step to do the math. Is it possible to change the units from `px` to `em` in Chrome Developer Tools?

**EDIT: Images uploaded**

[image]

Comment: you mean the `computed style / metrics`?  The regular `styles` should show the the width in the same units you set

Comment: Uploaded an image to clarify what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. The box dimensions are just the `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` of the focused element displayed there for your convenience.